# Deducing ordering from inequalities

Tags: inequality

Given $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$a + b < c + d$$
$$a + c < b + d$$

can we say anything further about the relative ordering of $a,b,c,d$ other than $a<d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Nothing between $a$ and $b$ : Take $(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,2,3),(1,2,3,4)$ and $(2,1,3,5)$.
- Nothing between $a$ and $c$ : Take $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,1,3),(1,1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,1,5)$.
- Nothing between $b$ and $c$ : Take $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,0,2),(1,1,2,4)$ and $(1,2,1,3)$.
- Nothing between $b$ and $d$ : Take $(a,b,c,d)=(-1,0,0,0),(1,0,0,2)$ and $(-2,2,0,1)$.
- Nothing between $c$ and $d$ : Take $(a,b,c,d)=(-1,0,0,0),(1,0,0,2)$ and $(-4,-2,2,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

At least nothing between $a$ and $c$ since
$$-1+1<1+0,-1+1<1+0$$ $$(a=-1,b=1,c=1,d=0)$$

And 
$$ 1+1<-1+10,1+(-1)<1+10$$ $$(a=1,b=1,c=-1,d=10)$$

Comment: I gave the tick to mathlove for completeness, but just wanted to acknowledge that your answer was submitted earlier with the same approach. I was looking for an algebraic proof, but the counter-example method is nice and direct. +1

Comment: Thnx and happy to help you.